# try with resources: detect exceptions?

Tags: java, try-catch

Here is an example code:

```
     try ( PgConnection conn = application.adminDb.getConnection() ) {
         // execute SQL statements here (and other possible statements)
     }
```

I would like that AutoCloseable PgConnection class to begin a new transaction when created, and COMMIT or ROLLBACK when it is closed. It should COMMIT if there was no exception thrown in the try block, and it should ROLLBACK otherwise.

What I really need is a context manager a'la Python. Is it possible to do this somehow? In theory, by the time PgConnection.close() is called, the JVM already knows if there was an exception or not. Just don't know how to tell that.

Of course I could make it explicit this way:

```
try ( PgConnection conn = application.adminDb.getConnection()) {

    conn.begin();
    try {
      // execute SQL statements here
      conn.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      conn.rollback();
      throw e;
    }

}
```

but I need to do this a hundred times, so I'm looking for an option that is "less noisy".

**UPDATE**

I could certainly do this:

```
public interface PgTransactionWrapper {
    public void run(PgConnection connection) throws SQLException;
}
```

And then put this into PgConnection:

```
   public void runInTransaction(PgTransactionWrapper wrapper) throws SQLException {
       int trId = begin();
       try {
           wrapper.run(this);
           commit(trId);
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           rollback(trId);
           throw e;
       }
   }
```

This is how it could be used:

```
     try ( PgConnection conn = application.adminDb.getConnection() ) {
         conn.runInTransaction(new PgTransactionWrapper() {

            @Override
            public void run(PgConnection connection) throws SQLException {
                // SQL statements here

            }
        });
     }
```

But I think it is even worse. It is true that auto commit/rollback is achieved, but the price to pay is even more syntax noise, and an extra problem is introduced: the transaction wrapper cannot throw anything other than SQLException.

What I miss is a simple argument to AutoCloseable.close(Exception excOrNull) but I guess that is a limitation of the language, and it cannot be done. :-(

**UPDATE 2**: Just to clarify the question: I do not want to suppress or convert the exceptions. I just want to commit when there was no exception, and rollback when there was an exception. But otherwise, I do not want to handle them from inside - they should be propagated to the caller, unaltered.

Comment: An auto-closeable wrapper class around PgConnection which automatically commit/rollback on close depending the on state(default: unsucessful, unless explicitly set otherwise)?

Comment: Yes, but how to set the state? If I want to set the state in a catch clause, then I have to create an extra try/catch block for every singe use case. I think it would be worse than my "explicit" example, because it would still add syntax noise, and replace an explicit commit/rollback with an implicit one.

Comment: Your last example is noisy because you're not using lambda expressions, and has a problem with exceptions because you're still using checked exceptions rather than runtime exceptions (although it would be even less noisy if the try block was inside runInTransaction()). It would become quite clear if you used lamda expressions and runtime exceptions. And even cleaner if you used declarative transactions, as allowed by using AOP, using frameworks like Spring or CDI/EJBs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring aop. Can it handle nested transactions?

Comment: Btw SQLException is not a runtime exception. How could I not use it?

Comment: By catching it, wrapping it into a runtime exception, and throwing that runtime exception.

Comment: Well, okay, so you are suggesting to supress ANY kind of exception and convert ALL of them to runtime errors? I need a general solution/pattern to wrap a block of code into a transaction, and other kinds of exceptions needs to be handled from outside (e.g. from the caller).

Comment: I have looked at spring AOP. AOP advices work on methods. They cannot be used on code blocks, and they cannot be parametrized with variables declared locally. I think I want to achieve a very simple thing here, spring AOP would be a burden.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I had in mind with extending your code a bit. What do you think? Atleast you wouldn't have to catch exceptions and handle them all over the place to commit/rollback your transaction

```
public interface SQLStatementExecutor
{
    void run(PgConnection connection) throws SQLException;
}

public class PgConnectionWrapper implements Closeable
{

    private PgConnection connection;
    private boolean status = false;

    public PgConnectionWrapper()
    {
        connection = obtainConnection();
    }

    private PgConnection obtainConnection()
    {
        return application.adminDb.getConnection();
    }

    public void runInTransaction(SQLStatementExecutor executor) throws SQLException
    {
        try {
            executor.run(connection);
            status = true;
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            status = false;
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public PgConnection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }

    @Override public void close() throws IOException
    {
        if (status) {
            connection.commit();
        }
        else {
            connection.rollback();
        }

        connection.close();
    }
}

public class TestMain
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try (PgConnectionWrapper connectionWrapper = new PgConnectionWrapper()) {
            connectionWrapper.runInTransaction(new SQLStatementExecutor()
            {
                @Override public void run(PgConnection connection) throws SQLException
                {
                    // SQL statements, but no commit or rollback
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that I still can't throw anything from the code code other than SQLException. For example, I'm not able to mix MongoDb and PostgreSQL operations in the core code block, because MongoDb operations would throw a MongoQueryException. This is a real example - I actually need to support nested transactions, and execute different MongoDb operations depending on the success/failure of a nested PostgreSQL transaction. Regarding syntax noise, the plain explicit begin/commit/rollback seems much cleaner, easier to understand how it works, and does not limit the exceptions that can be thrown.

Comment: Have your considered to wrap the database specific exception into an exception of your type and handle them? I am pretty sure the above sample code could be re-written to handle nested transactions too by passing the ConnectionWrapper to SQLStatementExecutor instead of the PgConnection, with some work.

Comment: So you also suggest that I catch ALL possible exceptions, and convert them to something else. Then they can't be handled by the caller. But I do NOT want to handle these exceptions, nor I want to suppress/convert them to anything else. I just want to commit, or rollback, that's all. I think I'm looking for a language construct that simply does not exist in Java. :-(